# CR and LF characters shown at the end of each line in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I use Notepad++ as a text editor. Whenever I open any text file, Notepad++ shows two virtual characters `CR` and `LF`  at the end of each line. These characters are annoying in some cases, e.g. when reading application logs.

How do I remove or configure the display of these characters?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Toggle the setting View > Show Symbol > Show End of Line

As [Xenorose](https://superuser.com/a/409922/117590) [notes](https://superuser.com/questions/409919/cr-and-lf-charchters-at-end-of-line-in-notepad/409921#comment467080_409921), Show All Characters should also be unchecked.

[[image: Screenshot of setting]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGPyy.png)

Comment: You got there a few seconds before me. :) it should be noted that it might be the "all characters" that's marked.

Comment: i dont have that option checked, but LF is still showing. If i toggle the option, i get LF and CR, if i turn it off again, im back to just LF at the end of the lines. is this a bug?

Comment: hmmm, i saved the document and closed notepad++ then re-opened it, and the LFs went away, must have been a temporary glitch

Comment: I also had this what you call *temporary glitch*.

Answer (score 7):

In the menu go to :
view > Show Symbols
You probably have one of these checked: "Show end of line" or "show all characters"  .
Uncheck them (only one can be selected, deselect the one you have checked).

Answer (score 6):

If you are seeing something like this (Block carriage return (CR) and linefeed (LF) characters after pressing 'Return' or 'Enter' key on the keyboard):

[image]

You can fix it by clicking the ¶ icon on the toolbar.

[image]

Comment: This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.

Comment: @Atta H. this is actually useful toggle button, thanks

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to the answer, there is also an **Icon** on **Main Notepad++ interface** to **disable/enable** these special characters.

### Disabled

[image: Notepad++ show characters]

### Enabled

[image: Notepad++ show characters - enabled]

*It saves about two mouse clicks!*

Here is a quick one minute video of how to [Show All Characters in Notepad++](https://youtu.be/8GWjRe-0shk).

**Disclaimer**: This video is from my YouTube channel, which demonstrates all steps required to answer this question.